# Find the order of differential equation of family of circles touching two given circles externally.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, circles

> Find the order of differential equation of family of circles touching two given circles externally.

**My Attempt:**

Let the first circle ($S_1$) be $x^2+y^2+2g_1x+2f_1y+c_1=0$ and the other circle ($S_2$) be $x^2+y^2+2g_2x+2f_2y+c_2=0$

Let the family of circles be $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$

Since the family of circles is touching the given circles externally, so,

$$C_1C_3-r_1=C_2C_3-r_2$$

where $C_1,C_2$ are the centres of the given circles and $r_1,r_2$ being their radii. And $C_3,r_3$ are the centre and radius of the family of circles.

Thus, I'll get one equation in $\lambda$. Therefore the required order is $1$.

**Is this correct?**

My major doubt is regarding the step $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ (generally we write this for intersecting circles)

**Edit:**

My approach is wrong. As, $C_1C_3-r_1=C_2C_3-r_2$ will be an equation in $g_1,g_2,f_1,f_2,c_1,c_2,\lambda$ but not in $x,y$. So, I won't get a differential equation from this.

Comment: Do you need an equation for the conic section describing the family of curves or just an implicit derivative of a circle equation?

Comment: @Christian I am looking for an answer that satisfactorily explains how the answer of the given question is $1$.

Comment: For constant $c, ~\frac {r_1+r}{r_2+r}= c,$ or $ r= \frac{r_1-r_2 c}{c-1}=r$ is always a part of an Apollonian circle.. just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the centres and radii of the given circles be $z_1,z_2$ and $r_1,r_2$. Assuming $r_1\ge r_2$

Let the centre of a circle that touches the given circles externally is $z$.

Therefore, $$|z-z_1|-r_1=|z-z_2|-r_2\\ \implies |z-z_1|-|z-z_2|=r_1-r_2$$

This represents hyperbola with focii at $z_1,z_2$ and the length of transverse axis $r_1-r_2$

In Cartesian form, the hyperbola is $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Since $a$ is given here i.e. $\frac{r_1-r_2}2$, that means there is only one arbitrary constant here i.e. $b$.

Therefore, the order of the differential equation is $1$.

Comment: The hyperbola only describes the location of the centers of the circles which isnt what you asked for. I also dont see why the order of a DE should be one because it has one arbitrary constant

Comment: @Christian I have used $C_1C_3-r_1=C_2C_3-r_2$

Answer (score 0):

A family of circles can be described by

$$x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$$

regardless of whether they are tangent to two given circles. $f, g, c$ just depend on the position and radii of these given circles and an additional parameter $\lambda$. To obtain a differential equation differentiate implicitly and rearrange,

$$2x \, \mathrm{d}x + 2y \, \mathrm{d}y + 2g\, \mathrm{d}x + 2f\, \mathrm{d}y = 0 \\ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} (y + f) + x + g = 0$$

the order of which is one.